# Wrapping things up in opengl based library

Tags: opengl, c++

I am currently building a render library, based on opengl : problem is that I'm starting to get a lot of different ccomponents (Shaders, Materials, Textures, Meshes, ...), and I'm trying to wrap things up, without any success; I've had several ideas, like making a render class, or a scene class, but it did not turn out well...[enter link description here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97025/renderbatch-for-game-engine). So I would ask you if any of you can suggest a way to wrap things up, if possible, still allowing the user to access Shaders, and low level rendering ! Here is the main code where I use all my objects :

Main.cpp :

```
/**
    PLEASE IGNORE : this is a test file for the alpha++ library !
*/


#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_inverse.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>
#include "alpha/Shader.h"
#include "alpha/Window.h"
#include "alpha/Vertex.h"
#include "alpha/Mesh.h"
#include "alpha/Texture.h"
#include "alpha/Material.h"
#include "alpha/Transform.h"
#include "alpha/Camera.h"
#include "alpha/ModelLoader.h"
#include "alpha/InputHandler.h"
#include "alpha/wrapper/SDL_Handle.h"
//#include "alpha/LuaLoader.h" ///WARNING : INCLUDING LuaLoader SERIOUSLY increases compile time (~ 10 seconds)
#include "alpha/Util.h"
#include "alpha/FPSLook.h"
#include "alpha/Light.h"

static const unsigned WIDTH = 1000.0;
static const unsigned HEIGHT = 900.0;
static const unsigned FPS = 200;
static const float MOUSE_SENSITIVITY = 5.0;
static const glm::ivec2 MOUSE_TRAP(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
static const float CAMERA_MOVE_SPEED = 0.01;
static bool isRunning = false;

int main(int argc, char **args){
    Window window(300, 100, WIDTH, HEIGHT, "This is a test !", false, false);
    window.SetMouseVisible(false);

    //Material material;
    //material.AddTexture("grid_metal", new Texture("res/MercureRelief.png", GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LINEAR));

    Texture texture("res/MercureRelief.png", GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_NEAREST);

    Mesh mesh("res/Test.obj");
    Mesh lightMesh("res/cube.obj");
    Shader shader;
    shader.loadFromFile(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "res/basicShader.glslv");
    shader.loadFromFile(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "res/phongShader.glslf");
    shader.CreateAndLink();
    Camera camera(glm::vec3(0, 0, 2.5), 70.0f, (float)window.GetWidth() / (float)window.GetHeight(), 0.01, 1000.0f);
    Transform transform;
    InputHandler input = InputHandler();
    glm::mat4 modelView = transform.GetModelView();
    glm::mat4 projectionView;
    glm::mat4 modelViewProjection;
    glm::mat3 normalMatrix;
    glm::vec3 cameraPosition;
    float time = .0f;
    float materialShininess = 100.0f;
    glm::vec3 materialSpecularColor = glm::vec3(2.0, 4.0, 6.0);
    PhongLight phongLight;
    phongLight.position = glm::vec3(5.0, 5.0, -5.0);
    phongLight.intensities = glm::vec3(2.0, 4.0, 5.0);
    phongLight.attenuation = 0.25f;
    phongLight.ambientCoeff = 0.0008f;

    isRunning = true;
    util::InMainLoop(3000, isRunning,
    [&](float delta){
        shader.Bind();

        static float timer = 0;
        timer += 0.0005;

        transform.GetScale() = glm::vec3(timer , timer , timer);
        transform.GetRot() += glm::vec3(timer / 20, timer / 20, timer / 20);

        normalMatrix = glm::inverseTranspose(glm::mat3(modelView));
        modelViewProjection =  camera.Combined() * transform.GetModelView();
        cameraPosition = -camera.GetPosition();


        glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("MVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelViewProjection));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("modelView"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelView));
        glUniformMatrix3fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("normalMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(normalMatrix));
        shader.UpdateUniform3fv("light.lightPosition", glm::value_ptr(phongLight.position));
        shader.UpdateUniform3fv("light.lightIntensities", glm::value_ptr(phongLight.intensities));
        shader.UpdateUniform3fv("cameraPosition", glm::value_ptr(cameraPosition));
        shader.UpdateUniform3fv("materialSpecularColor" ,glm::value_ptr(materialSpecularColor));
        shader.UpdateUniform1f("light.lightAttenuation", phongLight.attenuation);
        shader.UpdateUniform1f("light.lightAmbientCoeff", phongLight.ambientCoeff);
        shader.UpdateUniform1f("materialShininess", materialShininess);

        window.Update();
        input.Update();
        isRunning = !(input.CloseRequested() || input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE));
        util::ApplyFreeFPSLook(camera, input, window, delta, CAMERA_MOVE_SPEED, MOUSE_SENSITIVITY, MOUSE_TRAP);
     }
    ,
    [&](){
        window.Clear(.0f, .0f, .0f, .0f);
        texture.Bind();
        mesh.Draw();
        window.SwapBuffers();
    }
    );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;// :) Nothing bad happened
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks not too bad to me. Only thoughts are to consolidate your camera to have a setMVPUniform(GLuint uloc, matrix model) or similar function. Likewise make similar classes for Lights, textures, VAOs, etc. Wrap anything you find yourself copypasting into a function.

As long as you keep your things public you'll still have low level access where needed.

Definitely make a renderer class for each group of objects which share the same program.

```
class Renderer{
    vector<object> objects;
    shader;

    void renderAll(camera cam){
        bindShaderLightsMaterials();
        for(objects){
            cam.setUniform( shader.uloc("cam"), object.trans );
            object.bindVAO();
            render();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You say I should store MVP in camera ? how ?

Comment: 2) Should I make a scene object that stores MVP ?

Comment: Store individual fields for view and projection, then in the setUniform take model transformation as a parameter and multiply them. You could be more efficient by precomputing viewprojection every time you set view.

Comment: 3
) How can I update light, texture, or things like that in the camera ? Why in the camera ?

Comment: "likewise", as in make other classes for those things the same as you did camera. You could also consolidate all that into a Scene like you suggested.

Comment: so I pass ModelView to the camera; do I pass Transform too ?

Comment: Although I would leave the Scene functionality to the Renderer class and use polymorph appropriately, otherwise youll have a huge number of messy parameters.

Comment: The camera stores its transformations and anything else which is relatively consistent per pass as member variables. Model transformation is not consistent and thus a parameter.

Comment: I see... I wrap everythin into functions (like opengl 1/2.x); Just a last question : you mentioned "setUniform" in the camera class... I should add a setUniform method in my camera class, and  take in modelView, materials, and light objects ?

Comment: No, just model, not view or projection, not other non-camera uniforms, do those in your Renderer class.

Comment: Ok,I already attempted a render class here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97025/renderbatch-for-game-engine , but it did not turn out well... Can you post the skeleton of the render class (just psedo code) in your answer please ?